# Query List of Opportunities in Apex

Tags: apex, opportunity

Hi I have created the following class, in Apex . For now I just want to query the Opportunity of the person that has logged in, into salesforce and have it showing , eventually I need to show the recent ones that they have created, but I get an error, Unexpected Token for my Opp query . Updating the code to

```
 public with sharing class OppExt {



     public List<Opportunity> myOpportunities { get; private set; }

     public OppExt(){
     myOpportunities = [ SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name
                 from Opportunity 
                 WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

 }
 //Set<Opportunity> ids = new Set<Opportunity>();

public List<Opportunity> getOpp() {

   //for (Opportunity O : myOpportunities){
   //   ids.add(O.Name);
   //}
   // return ids;
   return myOpportunities;

}

}
```

Apex page

```
<apex:repeat value="getOpp" var="op">
            <apex:outputText value="{!op[Name]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Your "select" "Where" clause will need to mention the "ownerid" field for the selection as a minimum. Also, there is not enough structure or code here for anyone to answer a question.

Comment: @AntSmith that is all I have written. I am learning this right now. so is this wrong for querying opportunities? I guess I need a for loop somewhere to fill up the opportunities in it

Comment: Although we are trying to answer specific questions here, my comment is to clarify that listing all opportunities for a particular OWNER requires the WHERE clause to select the specific OWNER. The ID of a record does not identify the OWNER, it simply identifies the record. You will need to package the corrected code into a controller and invoke this by means of a visualforce page before you can invoke it correctly. I suspect you are some way away from having a question specific enough to be answered here.

Comment: @AntSmith well i guess this would public List<User> u {get;set;}

     u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

Comment: @AntSmith I just updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a syntactic perspective, you need to move your code into a constructor where the `ApexPages.StandardController` you are hoping for in your `std` variable will be defined. Right now `std` appears to be undefined.

```
public OppExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    Opportunity opp = [SELECT ... FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :controller.getId()];
}
```

According to the comment thread you may instead want to filter on a `User` lookup, in which case this class would really be a controller, not an extension, since you wouldn't need the `StandardController` at all.

```
public with Sharing class MyOpportunitiesController
{
    public List<Opportunity> myOpportunities { get; private set; }
    public MyOpportunitiesController()
    {
        myOpportunities = [
            SELECT ... FROM Opportunity
            WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: so this public List<User> u {get;set;}

     u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; doesnt work? to pass the value of the current logged in user?

Comment: Does this work [SELECT Opportunity.Opportunity_Name,
                             Opportunity.Opportunity_Owner,
                             Opportunity.Amount,
                             Opportunity.Close_Date
                        FROM Opportunity
                       WHERE Account__c = :UserInfo.getAccountId()

Comment: Your question is mostly about `SOQL` syntax and doesn't really have anything to do with `User` ids as written...

Comment: i updated to this now 'public with sharing class OppExt {
 
    public List<Opportunity> Opp {get;set;}
       Opp = [ SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name
                 from Opportunity 
                 WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

 
 Set<Opportunity> ids = new Set<Opportunity>();
        
public List<Opportunity> getOpp() {

   for (Opportunity O : Opp){
    ids.add(O.Name);
   }
    return ids;
}
}'

Comment: Thank you I just updated the code, do I add the opportunities correctly to my Set?

Comment: You are mixing your types up quite badly. It is impossible to even decipher what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I fixed the other side, in the page this doesnt work <apex:repeat value="getOpp" var="op">
   <apex:outputText value="{!op.name}"/>
   </apex:repeat>

Comment: Change `getOpp` to `Opp`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this pull in the current user's ID that could then be used to query against?

```
public OppExt() {

}
public user currentuser{get;set;}

    public List<Opportunity> Opp {get;set;}
    public List<User> u {get;set;}

     u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
     Opp = [SELECT Id,OwnerId,Name,Account.OwnerId FROM Opportunity Where Id =:std.getId() and ownerid:u[0].id];


public List<Opportunity> getOpp() {

    return List<Opportunity> Opp;

}
```

Comment: it says Unexpected token "="  for this line u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

Comment: Your query on `User` is blatantly wasteful usage

Comment: Something more like

Opp = [SELECT Id,OwnerId,Name,Account.OwnerId FROM Opportunity Where OwnerId =::UserInfo.getUserId() ;

but your own debugging mileage may vary.